# ajax/json/? to query a webpage and return specifc div/p values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to find code or a way to process the following:

When you click a button a site it'll go and read specific website link and then return variables that it finds in the remote page.

1) user clicks button
2) query goes to www.whatever.com/myfile.html
3) there is a specific p tag inside a div tag called 'totalamount' =  
  `<div id=WTextWrapper><p id="Amount">2,000</p></div>` 
That I want to grab the value of and then display it on my page below the button that I clicked in step 1

I know there is a way to do it, but I have no idea how it's done.

Comment: As a Java developer, i'd use Jsoup to do this. So, if i were you, i'd look for a Jsoup equivalent for PHP. Something like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: simplehtmldom looks like it'll work for me, but when i put the code in to pull data, i just get an answer of "Array" when i echo the results of the data pull, and i don't know what to do after that.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with simplehtmldom to be much help with that. Best bet is probably to write up another question showing the problematic code and the results of running it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the source of the html and use regex to extract what you need. You can use file_get_contents() function to get the source html.